# Using Javascript Vue and having problems linking tabs so that when user clicks tab button they are directed to new page. Do I need to use router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sidebar

This is in sidebar.vue tab:

```
<script> 
export default {
    name: 'SidebarMenu',
    props: {
      //! Menu settings
      isMenuOpen: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
      },
      menuTitle: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
      },
      menuLogo: {
        type: String,
        default: '',
      },
      menuIcon: {
        type: String,
        default: 'bx-planet',
      },
      isPaddingLeft: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: true,
      },
       menuOpenedPaddingLeftBody: {
        type: String,
        default: '250px'
      },
      menuClosedPaddingLeftBody: {
        type: String,
        default: '78px'
      },

      //! Menu items
      menuItems: {
        type: Array,
        default: () => [
          {
            link: 'Home.vue',
            name: 'Home',
            tooltip: 'Home',
            icon: 'bx-grid-alt',
          },
          {
            link: 'About-Me.vue',
            name: 'About Me',
            tooltip: 'About Me',
            icon: 'bx-user',
          },
          {
            link: 'Contact.vue',
            name: 'Contact',
            tooltip: 'Contact',
            icon: 'bx bx-envelope',
          },
          {
            link: 'Projects.vue',
            name: 'Projects',
            tooltip: 'Projects',
            icon: 'bx-pie-chart-alt-2',
          },
        ],
      },
```

Comment: Please be more specific with your problem; for example, what have you tried? what is happening vs what you expect to happen? and include all relevant code samples

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.